# Why should we use IP spoofing when performance testing?

Tags: performance, jmeter, ip, performance-testing, loadrunner

Could anyone please tell me what is the use of IP spoofing in terms of Performance Testing?

Answer (score 6):

There are two main reasons for using IP spoofing while load testing a web application:

1. **Routing stickiness** (a.k.a *Persistence*) - Many load balancers use IP stickiness when distriuting incoming load across applications servers. So, if you generate the load from the same IP, you could load only one application server instead of distributing the load to all application servers (This is also called *Persistence*: When we use Application layer information to stick a client to a single server). Using IP spoofing, you avoid this stickiness and make sure your load is distributed across all application servers.
2. **IP Blocking** - Some web applications detect a mass of HTTP requests coming from the same IP and block them to defend themselves. When you use IP spoofing you avoid being detected as a harmful source.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to load testing of web applications well behaved test should represent real user using real browser as close as possible, with all its stuff like:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [Cache](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)
- Handling of "embedded resources" (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.)
- [Think times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997697.aspx)

You might need to simulate requests originating from the different IP addresses if your application (or its infrastructure, like [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))) assumes that each user uses unique IP address. Also [DNS Caching](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) on operating system of JVM level may lead to the situation when all your requests are basically hitting only one endpoint while others remain idle. So if there is a possibility it is better to mimic the requests in that way so they would come from the different addresses.